# Generate MD5 hash for a list of integers

Tags: java, md5

I have a list of Integer

```
List<Integer> listInt;
```

I want to generate a MD5 hash for the listInt how should I approach the problem, I know that I have to use

```
MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(byte[])
```

How do I convert the listInt to bytes.

Comment: Are you trying to get an MD5 hash of every integer in the list, or a single MD5 hash of the integers in the list?

Comment: Single MD5 hash of the integers in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert each integer value to 4 bytes, forming an array of bytes that is `4*listInt.size()` bytes long.

One way to do this is to make use of NIO's [ByteBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4*listInt.size());
buf.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
for (int i = 0; i < listInt.size(); ++i)
    buf.putInt(listInt.get(i));
byte[] barr = buf.array();
```

Note that there are two common ways of converting an array of integers to an array of bytes. The difference, however, is simply the choice of [Endianness](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Endianness). Some people choose to calculate the Big Endian byte representation of integers; others choose to calculate the little Endian representation of integers. It doesn't matter which method you pick as long as you calculate the byte representation of each integer consistently.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte data[] = new byte[listInt.size()*4];
for (int i = 0; i < listInt.size(); i++) {
  data[i*4]   = new Integer(listInt.get(i) >> 24).byteValue();
  data[i*4+1] = new Integer(listInt.get(i) >> 16).byteValue();
  data[i*4+2] = new Integer(listInt.get(i) >> 8).byteValue();
  data[i*4+3] = listInt.get(i).byteValue();
}
```

Sample code running: http://ideone.com/YJZVj

Answer (score 1):

First create a method that converts an int to a byte array:

```
  public static final byte[] intToByteArray(int value) 
  { 
    return new byte[]  { (byte)(value >>> 24), (byte)(value >> 16 & 0xff), (byte)(value >> 8 & 0xff), (byte)(value & 0xff) };
  }
```

Then use a ByteArrayOutputStream.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

for (int i = 0; i < listInt.size(); i++)
{
  baos.write(intToByteArray(listInt[i]), 0, 4);
}
```

You will then get your full byte array to perform the md5 hash on by:

```
byte[] fullByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: +1 for using the *unsigned* right shift operator to obtain the most-significant byte of `value`.